# OpenCV: Understanding warpPerspective / perspective transform

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, perspective

I made a small example for myself to play around with OpenCVs wrapPerspective, but the output is not completely as I expected.

My input is a bar at an 45° angle. I want to transform it so that it's vertically aligned / at an 90° angle. No problem with that. However, what I don't understand is that everything around the actual destination points is black. The reason I don't understand this is, that actually only the transformation matrix gets passed to the wrapPerspective function, not the destination points themselves. So my expected output would be a bar at an 90° angle and most around it to be yellow instead of black. Where's my error in reasoning?

```
# helper function
def showImage(img, title):
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.suptitle(title)
    plt.imshow(img)


# read and show test image
img = mpimg.imread('test_transform.jpg')
showImage(img, "input image")


# source points
top_left = [194,430]
top_right = [521,103]
bottom_right = [549,131]
bottom_left = [222,458]
pts = np.array([bottom_left,bottom_right,top_right,top_left])


# target points
y_off = 400; # y offset
top_left_dst = [top_left[0], top_left[1] - y_off]
top_right_dst = [top_left_dst[0] + 39.6, top_left_dst[1]]
bottom_right_dst = [top_right_dst[0], top_right_dst[1] + 462.4]
bottom_left_dst = [top_left_dst[0], bottom_right_dst[1]]
dst_pts = np.array([bottom_left_dst, bottom_right_dst, top_right_dst, top_left_dst])

# generate a preview to show where the warped bar would end up
preview=np.copy(img)
cv2.polylines(preview,np.int32([dst_pts]),True,(0,0,255), 5)
cv2.polylines(preview,np.int32([pts]),True,(255,0,255), 1)
showImage(preview, "preview")


# calculate transformation matrix
pts = np.float32(pts.tolist())
dst_pts = np.float32(dst_pts.tolist())
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts, dst_pts)

# wrap image and draw the resulting image
image_size = (img.shape[1], img.shape[0])
warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, dsize = image_size, flags = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
showImage(warped, "warped")
```

The result using this code is:

[image]

Here's my input image test_transform.jpg:
[image]
And here is the same image with coordinates added:
[image]

By request, here is the transformation matrix:

```
[[  6.05504680e-02  -6.05504680e-02   2.08289910e+02]
 [  8.25714275e+00   8.25714275e+00  -5.12245707e+03]
 [  2.16840434e-18   3.03576608e-18   1.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: can you output the transformation matrix? Ich guess there are some quite big perspective part. If you just want to perform a 2D rotation and translation (affine transformation without perspective part), the last row should be (0,0,1). You can compute a 2D rotation by composing it with Translation (rotation center to 0), Rotation around (0,0) (with some angle) and another Translation to move the center back to the original position or wherever you want your object to be placed. Those operations can be combined to a single transformation matrix.

Comment: @Micka: Added the transformation matrix at the end of my initial post. Actually this is only a reduced example/test, finally I want to transform street lanes (car perspective to bird eye perspective)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ordering in your arrays or their positions might be the fault. Check this Transformed  Image: The dst_pts array is: np.array([[196,492],[233,494],[234,32],[196,34]]), thats more or less like the blue rectangle in your preview image.(I made the coordinates myself to make sure they are right)
**NOTE:** Your source and destination points should be in right order

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer. The `top_left` of the angled bar corresponds to the `bottom_left` of the vertical bar (and all others follow that same mistake). And that's why the top and bottom of the vertical bar is blurry and why the yellow is so narrow in OPs warped picture.

Comment: Thank you guys, you two are right! Fixed, working source points for me were `top_left = [521,103]
top_right = [549,131]
bottom_right = [222,458]
bottom_left = [194,430]` and I adapted the offset: `y_off = 50`